# How to sort table in phpliteadmin database?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, sorting

i cant use the below code to sort my database permanently:-

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ORDER BY column DESC;
```

anyone can help? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: btw, i am using phpliteadmin database.. i dont how to do it actually..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create an index oriented table (from the SQL Server world this would be a table clustered on an index, and in MySQL, it would be the primary key on an InnoDB table).

SQLite does not support such a feature.  You cannot permanently set a logical access order to the table.  What you can do is set various secondary indexes which are themselves ordered to provide that sort of ordered access to the data.

However, keep in mind that a logical order index scan over the whole table is usually slower than scanning the whole table and sorting, so it may or may not solve any performance problems.

Comment: okay thank you for your advice and answer.. So, i guess i dont have to do it but i can rearrange on my external sql code (copy, arrange, copy back)..

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean here.  SQL is intended to say "here's what I want.  I don't care how you get it."

In theory you could create a new table periodically using select into.....  but updates will disturb the physical ordering (PostgreSQL uses a similar approach btw).